# Replacing new line characters with literal '\n' in macvim

Tags: vim, macvim

I want to replace all new line characters with the two literal characters '\' and 'n' in macvim under a selected area.

For example

i have selected the following lines (in .js file) :

```
# /messages/{id}

## GET
+ Response 200 (text/plain)

        Hello World!

## DELETE
+ Response 204
```

Then i am applying

```
:'<,'>s#\n#/\n#g
```

that replaces into :

```
'# /messages/{id}/^@/^@## GET/^@+ Response 200 (text/plain)/^@/^@       Hello World!/^@/^@## DELETE/^@+ Response 204'/^@
```

My desired output is :

```
# /messages/{id}/\n/\n## GET/\n+ Response 200 (text/plain)/\n/\n       Hello World!/\n/\n## DELETE/\n+ Response 204'/\n
```

Why there is `^@` instead of `\n`?

And how can i get `\n`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\n` in the search part of your substitution and `\r` in the replace part:

```
:%s#\n#/\r#g
```

***EDIT***

Oh! Do you want to replace all EOLs with literal `\n`?

```
:%s/\n/\\n
```

Comment: i got # /messages/{id}/
/
## GET/
+ Response 200 (text/plain)/
/
        Hello World!/
/
## DELETE/
+ Response 204/ result... Not desired one. and new line characters are still present there

Comment: This is the solution, because your error was in failing to escape the replacement text. In the replacement, "\n" as a string has special meaning. You needed to escape it with an additional '\' character to remove the special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

```
:'<,'>s#\n#/&#g
```

or

```
:'<,'>s#\n#/\r#g
```

Comment: with second : i got # /messages/{id}/
/
## GET/
+ Response 200 (text/plain)/
/
        Hello World!/
/
## DELETE/
+ Response 204/ result... Not desired one. with first i got only one replace of \ with \n and new line characters are still present there

Comment: as i mentioned in question i was getting '^@' instead of '\n'.. i corrected the question with desired output